# How can I get the width of a ChildNode in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React and Typescript to build a carousel of tabs where each tab has a different size. I need to get these tab sizes to correctly calculate how many tabs fit in each view. How can I get the width of each such child node in React?

I was able to retrieve tab nodes using ref:

```js
const tabs = tabsRef.current;
tabs.childNodes.forEach((tab: ChildNode) => {
    // I need the width of the tab here
});
```

I tried using `tab.clientWidth`, however I got the following error `Property 'clientWidth' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'`.

I then tried a workaround

```js
tab.firstChild.parentElement.clientWidth;
```

However, this throws an exception for elements that don't have a child. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what exactly you want. But you can log the `ref` in the console, and look for what you want in there.

Comment: Did you try `tab.clientWidth`?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I want to get the width of the tab node.

Comment: @Chris I tried `tab.clientWidth`, however I got `Property 'clientWidth' does not exist on type 'ChildNode'.

Comment: `tabsContainerRef.current.childNodes.forEach(...)`

Answer (score 4):

[ChildNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode) is a mixin and as so it doesn't contain any width properties as some of the nodes might have no width (ie. DocumentType). However, if you know the type(s) of your child nodes, you can use cast to make typescript happy:

```
(tabs.childNodes as NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement>).forEach((tab: HTMLDivElement) => {

    console.log(tab.offsetWidth);
    console.log(tab.clientWidth);
})
```

In case you have multiple element types you can define them all:

```
const tabsChildren = tabs.childNodes as NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement | HTMLSpanElement | HTMLButtonElement>;
```

or just use `any` as the last resort fix:

```
const tabsChildren = tabs.childNodes as NodeListOf<any>;
```